# xsl number returning unexpected result

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

This fragment of XML contains the elements `sic` , `del`, and `surplus` to which I would like to add a count `a, b, c` etc in a new attribute `n`:

```
<body xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
    <ab>
        <seg>Lorem<sic att="sictest1">sic <ref>1</ref> content</sic> ipsum dolor sit amet, 
            consectetur<del att="deltest1">del <ref>1</ref> content</del> adipiscing elit. 
            Sed elementum lorem ac purus<surplus att="surptest1">surplus <ref>1</ref> 
            content</surplus> bibendum, ut cursus sapien auctor. Nam lacinia ante in 
            ultricies ultrices. Pellentesque<surplus att="surptest2">surplus <ref>2</ref> 
            content</surplus> accumsan ligula<sic att="sictest2">sic <ref>2</ref> 
            content</sic> vitae facilisis mattis.</seg>
    </ab>
</body>
```

However this XSL :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" 
    version="3.0">
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
    
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
        
    <!-- set letters to apparatus -->
    <xsl:template match="tei:sic | tei:del | tei:surplus">
        <xsl:variable name="fn">
            <xsl:number count="." format="a" level="any"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="name" select="name(.)"/>
        <xsl:element name="{ $name }" namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"></xsl:copy-of>
            <xsl:attribute name="n">
                <xsl:value-of select="$fn"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is returning the XML below, where the values for attribute `n` are `h, n, t, z, af`:

```
<body xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
    <ab>
        <seg>Lorem<sic att="sictest1" n="h">sic <ref>1</ref> content</sic> ipsum dolor sit amet, 
            consectetur<del att="deltest1" n="n">del <ref>1</ref> content</del> adipiscing elit. 
            Sed elementum lorem ac purus<surplus att="surptest1" n="t">surplus <ref>1</ref> 
            content</surplus> bibendum, ut cursus sapien auctor. Nam lacinia ante in 
            ultricies ultrices. Pellentesque<surplus att="surptest2" n="z">surplus <ref>2</ref> 
            content</surplus> accumsan ligula<sic att="sictest2" n="af">sic <ref>2</ref> 
            content</sic> vitae facilisis mattis.</seg>
    </ab>
</body>
```

But I am expecting the following:

```
<body xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
    <ab>
        <seg>Lorem<sic att="sictest1" n="a">sic <ref>1</ref> content</sic> ipsum dolor sit amet, 
            consectetur<del att="deltest1" n="b">del <ref>1</ref> content</del> adipiscing elit. 
            Sed elementum lorem ac purus<surplus att="surptest1" n="c">surplus <ref>1</ref> 
            content</surplus> bibendum, ut cursus sapien auctor. Nam lacinia ante in 
            ultricies ultrices. Pellentesque<surplus att="surptest2" n="d">surplus <ref>2</ref> 
            content</surplus> accumsan ligula<sic att="sictest2" n="e">sic <ref>2</ref> 
            content</sic> vitae facilisis mattis.</seg>
    </ab>
</body>
```

Fiddle [here](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/aKZkhp).

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The solution is changing the value of attribute `count` to the nodes, and not using the context node. i.e. `<xsl:number count="tei:sic | tei:del | tei:surplus" format="a" level="any"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `count` attribute is a pattern, which indicates which nodes should be counted. The value `count="."` matches all nodes, so all nodes are counted. Try `count="tei:sic | tei:del | tei:surplus"`.